# How did Madara really obtain his Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

Regarding Madara's Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan, there are three canon stories on how he obtained it.

The first version is mentioned by Itachi, while explaining the Mangekyou to Sasuke. In this version, he tells that Madara took his brother's eyes. Itachi shows the scene to Sasuke through Genjutsu, where Madara places his fingers over Izuna's eye and Izuna is surprised by the action. This would mean a forceful extraction.

The second version is told by Obito, acting as Madara. He explains to Sasuke that Izuna willingly gave his eyes to him (Madara), to protect the clan from the dangers of the fame.

The third version is told by the First Hokage, Hashirama Senju, when he was reincarnated by Orochimaru. He tells that Izuna succumbed to the wounds (during the warring period) caused by Tobirama Senju. And it is assumed that Madara took his brother's eyes after he died.

So which version is the actual one? Or is it a mix of all three?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the last version, Hashirama's, is correct. Normally over time, a story gets told in different ways because everyone hears it differently. Which would make sense to why Obito's and Itachi's differ from each other and from Hashirama's (because after years they heard it differently?). I'm not sure tho, Hashirama could also be wrong.

Comment: But Madara trained Obito himself. That's where my doubts root from.

Comment: Good point, but can we really assume Madara never lied to Obito? He kinda did brainwash him (in a way) into working with him. I wouldn't see the point in him lying about this, but we never know.

Comment: I guess. I can't think of any change in Obito or the entire plan if this detail was lied about..

Comment: Itachi wanted Sasuke to hate him so he could get stronger and showed him a force full version of the story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the data that is provided by the story, we don't have enough information to make a deduction. The only witnesses to the event were Madara and Izuna.

While this means that Madara's account has greater credibillity than anyone else, Madara has a reputation for deceiving people, such as Obito, with complex webs of lies and staged events. As a result, we cannot consider him a reliable information source.

**However**, based on information provided in the Naruto Data Book (Number 4, page 37) on Izuna, Izuna gave his eyes willingly. So we can conclude that Madara was telling the truth, at least in this case.

For access to the Japanese data book I reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/2l976c/spoilers_the_complete_4th_databook/

For the translation:
https://aminoapps.com/c/anime/page/blog/naruto-data-book-izuna-uchiha/WltX_uRVgmj1rLGwaPw7envXJ0MEjo

Comment: [Actually there night have been one more person who witnessed the entire chain of events..](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/3/32/Black_Zetsu%27s_True_Form.png/revision/latest/thumbnail-down/width/732/height/410?cb=20160528222827)

Comment: There is one person in the Narutoverse who I find a less reliable source of information than Madara. And you found him.

Answer (score 1):

Madara loved Izuna more than anyone else. Izuna was his precious little brother, he would never take his eyes by force. He took them after Tobirama killed Izuna, in order to not let his death be in vain.